# Text sentiment scoring returning <function sentiment_value at ...> instead of int score

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, tweets

I am trying to add a column to my twitter dataframe with a sentiment score.

I have tried the below code but I keep getting an output that isn't a 1, 0, or -1 int. as I am expecting

```
label =[ ]

from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

def sentiment_value(text):
    analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    result = analyser.polarity_scores(text)
    score = result['compound']
    if score >= 0.05:
        return 1
    elif (score > -0.05) and (score < 0.05):
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

Then I did a little test to see if this worked, which it seemed to:

```
# Input:

sample = tweets_df['tidy_tweet'][10]
print(sample)
print('Sentiment: ')
print(sentiment_value(sample))

# Output: 

that interest take seen cours approv through thi process wonder which one came core team shot down howev origin wonder what possibl could exist cours which there mani
Sentiment: 
1
```

Then I tried to apply the new sentiment_value function to the column I want to score

```
# I have named my clean tweets 'tidy_tweet'
# @handels,special characters, numbers, punctuations, short words have been removed
# Tweets have been tokenizen and stemmed 

for row in tweets_df['tidy_tweet']:
    label.append(sentiment_value)

tweets_df['label'] = label
```

When I call the new column, I was expecting to get a sentiment score, for example:

```
tweets_df['label'].head()

0      1
1      0
2      -1
3      0
4      -1
```

But what I actually get is:

```
0    <function sentiment_value at 0x10284b1e0>
1    <function sentiment_value at 0x10284b1e0>
2    <function sentiment_value at 0x10284b1e0>
3    <function sentiment_value at 0x10284b1e0>
4    <function sentiment_value at 0x10284b1e0>
```

I am very new to this and appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not calling the function. You should be doing this:

```
for row in tweets_df['tidy_tweet']:
    label.append(sentiment_value(row))  # note that row is now passed to sentiment_value

tweets_df['label'] = label
```

You can also use a `list` comprehension:

```
tweets_df['label'] = [sentiment_value(tweet) for tweet in tweets_df['tidy_tweet']
```

Or even `transform`:

```
tweets_df['label'] = tweets_df['tidy_tweet'].transform(sentiment_value)
```